# tumblr as a backend-solution for a flex/actionscript app?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, backend, tumblr

I love tumblr because it is so easy to use and you can generate xml's of all or parts of the content.
Does anybody have experience in using tumblr or similar platforms as a backend for flex/actionscript projects ? Advantages/Disantvantages?
Are there some minimalistic examples out there ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't do that. You would just need to develop a RSS reader via AS3. You can find examples [here](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=as3+rss+reader).